# inifinitely regressing "ls" drive under "Volumes"

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, git

First of all, I am aware the "ls" command means list all items in a directory.

Yesterday an icon appeared on my desktop with a picture of a drive labeled "ls". Looking in the terminal, I see that it is in the Volumes folder, and appears to contain everything on my mac, including a Volumes folder that contains an ls drive etc etc. I am not sure what to make of this. I looked at my terminal command history to see if I did something, and the only unusual use of "ls" I have it when I accidentally typed "git config ls" instead of "git config list" in the middle of other activity. I am new to git and was following a recipe, so don't know if config could cause something like this.

More info: When I create or alter a file (eg something like a screenshot that automatically saves to desktop), it appears / alters in the version of everything "inside" this ls drive, as though I am currently working inside of it all the time. The file also is accessible through (or a copy is accessible through) the normal path.

```
> diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.1 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     102.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ls                      11.1 GB    disk1s5
```

Comment: Can you give, from the terminal, the feedback `diskutil list`. This may give information about this pseudo disk.

Comment: Can you give, from the terminal, the feedback of the order: diskutil list This may give information about this pseudo disk.

Comment: Maybe it's a symbolic link to the root of the filesystem? Run `ls -lO@ /Volumes` to get more info on it.

Comment: @Jean_JD I guess I'm going to have to put it in an answer bc of the linebreaks issue with comments.

Comment: @GordonDavisson from the way the files are "duplicated" I think so. I ran yr command and got "total 0 [linebreak]
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  - 1 Apr 18 19:26 ls -> /"

But then what's up with #5 in the diskutil list; shouldn't it have the same size as either everything else or nothing? i've never actually knowingly created a root user, but it's very possible I did it by mistake screwing around following a recipe for something else (I'm a volunteer at a bootcamp in a subfield I don't work in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results of the command **diskutil list** show that the the Catalina system as be renamed **ls**  and should be named "Macintosh HD" because the "Data" drive is named "Macintosh HD - Data".

The terminal command:

```
diskutil rename disk1s5 "Macintosh HD"
```

will repair this.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just accidentally renamed the system volume to "ls", probably by typing it while not realizing the system volume's name was selected. I was able to reproduce your results by just renaming mine in the Finder. To change it back, go to the Finder's computer view (Choose Go menu > Computer, or press Command-Shift-C), select the disk "ls"'s name, change it to Macintosh HD, and press Return.

(Note: it's normal for there to be a symbolic link from `/Volumes/systemvolumename` to `/`.)

Answer (score 2):

No, typing `git config ls` in a Terminal is not going to cause the effect you have there.

I would unmount the `ls` folder, or just reboot the Mac to get back to normal.

Comment: I don't think I can unmount it, it looks like the highest thing there is (I can go "outside" it via terminal, but when I click show in enclosing folder in the gui, it just shows it parallel to "network" with nothing higher. by definition that must mean it's the root?